# Dualization map is surjective

Tags: functional-analysis, dual-spaces

I am practicing for my exam and I want to solve the following problem.

Let $X,Y$ be normed reflexive spaces. Show that the "Dualization map" $':B(X,Y)\to B(Y',X')$,  $T\mapsto T'$ is surjective

I want to use reflexivity since $X''$ and $X$, likewise for $Y$, are isometrically isomorphic. But I get stuck. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Maybe you should try and consider that $X’$ and $Y’$ are reflexive and consider two dualizations starting from $Y’ \rightarrow X’$.

Comment: But I don't know whether $X'$ is reflexive, since $X$ is not Banach

Comment: If you are using the usual definition, if $X$ is reflexive, $X$ is a Banach, no? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: You are right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: for every $U'\in B(Y',
X') $

Consider $U"=(U')':X"=X\rightarrow Y"=Y$.

Comment: Okay so I can show that $U''(x'')(y')=U''(\iota_X(x))(y')=\iota_X(x)\circ U'(y')=U'(y')(x)=y'\circ U(x)=i_Y(U(x))(y')$ but I don't really see how this helps

Comment: You can compute $(U") '=U' $.

Comment: I don't see what you mean

Comment: $(U") '(y') (x) =y'(U"(x)) =(U"(x)) (y') $, identify $U"(x) $ with an element of the bidual. $(U"(x))(y') =x((U'(y')) =U'(y') (x) $.